# C# homepage related question. (Request.Querystring["id"])

Tags: c#, mysql

i am currently working on a homepage for a guild that will come up and running in rift in the near future, thus i am trying to finish the homepage as fast as possible.

Anyway! i usually program homepages in VB.NET and i program c# when i program applications. but to become better at c# i choose to program the homepage in c#.

So heres my problem, i am currently trying to make a foreach that pulls out all the database stuff related to the id in the addressbar, so if my address bar says "ShowTopics.aspx?id=1" then everything in the table in the database that has the number 1 (i use a field called fldovertopicid so when someone adds a new under topic to the overtopic then it gets the same number as the overtopics id.) gets pulled out. though the problem is that it seems like it doesent work as easily as the vb.net programming does.

so heres my code:

in this code i give the method a name so that when i write that name later in my code it knows that, thats what its supposed to do. as you can see ive put a 'Where fldOverTopicID=" + id;' so i tell the code that i want to use fldOverTopicID as a mediator so that the code knows that when the addressbar number matches fldOverTopicID then its supposed to pull out everything with the same number.

```
public DataTable GetUnderTopics(int id)
    {
        string strsql = "select fldid, fldtopicname, fldicon, fldcreator from tbltopics where fldOverTopicId=" + id;
        MySqlCommand objCMD = new MySqlCommand(strsql);

        return _objdata.GetData(objCMD, _con);
    }
```

This is the backend code for where i want to pull out the topics. what im trying to tell it to do here is that if the number in the addressbar is 1 then its supposed to pull out all content that have a 1 in its fldOverTopicID. but this is were i get my problem. when i made that piece of code i got 2 errors:

1. The best overloaded method match for 'Forumfac.GetUnderTopics(int)' has some invalid arguments
2. Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'

   ```
       Forumfac objfac = new Forumfac();

       foreach (DataRow row in objfac.GetUnderTopics(Request.QueryString["id"]).Rows)
       {
       }
   ```

Hopefully i was able to explain my problem clearly enough.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `objFac.GetUnderTopics(int.Parse(Request.Querystring["id"]))`

You are making an invalid call to the method which takes an int as an argument.  All querystring parameters will be strings.  `int.Parse(string)` converts the value from a string to an integer or throws an exception if the string is not an integer.  There is also a `TryParse(string, out int)` method which returns whether or not the string could be converted and does not throw an exception.

Comment: thank you, i should honestly have thought of parsing it my self ^^

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
string idFromQueryString = Request.QueryString["id"];

if (! string.IsNullOrEmpty( idFromQueryString))
{
  int id = Convert.ToInt32(idFromQueryString );
  Forumfac objfac = new Forumfac();

  foreach (DataRow row in objfac.GetUnderTopics(id).Rows)
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answere StackOverflow, unfortunantly i can only choose one answere, and the other answere seemed alot easier to implement and works as well. thank you for taking your time to answere though

Answer (score 1):

I voted for StackOverflowException's answer because it should work.  But if I were writing this I'd use TryParse like this...

```
int id;
if (int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"], out id))
{
  Forumfac objfac = new Forumfac();

  foreach (DataRow row in objfac.GetUnderTopics(id).Rows)
  {
  }
}
```

It's one less step and it'll guarantee reliable results if the id can't be parsed.

Comment: well i dont see the difference though. ofcause i havent programmed website solutions for long with c#. either way what -Will Do- posted worked like a charm :)

Comment: The difference is when `Request.QueryString["id"]` equals something like "abc", `int.Parse` will throw an exception.  That won't happen if you use `int.TryParse` like in my example.